How to include all downstream fields in a solr query
I need to filter to the following, for example airport.location.*:open
like there will be many fields with airport.location.rdu, airport.location.lax, airport.location.lga etc. but I want to filter to any airport.location (regardless of rdu lax lga value) with value of open
Is this possible?
I tried airport.location*:open and airport.location.*:open but those do not filter, they don't register

Create a separate field that represents the unique open/closed values for a document, so that you can filter airport_has_locations_with_status:open instead. You can use a copyField instruction with source field set to airport.location.* to copy all the values from the different airport.location. fields into that common field.
